# How to prove mathematically these two different definitions of background-position property as equivalent?

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic, alternative-proof

I've been reading about how percentage values work for `background-position` position property. The official definition is that `background-position-x: p%` will move the image horizontally p% of the difference between the length of image and the container element. The same goes for `background-position-y: p%`. I found the [official definition here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-4/#the-background-position):

> "Percentages: refer to width of background positioning area minus height of background image"

The same defintion is used in [w3.org's tutorial](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_background_images#How_does_it_work.3F):

> "Percentages on the other hand move the image a percentage of the difference between the containing box size, and the image size."

I understand the concpet and this definiton well. But the problem is the [article on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/) uses a somewhat different definition:

> "moving a background image by X% means it will align the X% point in the image to the X% point in the container."

This definition literally means `background-position-x: p%` will first choose a point P' in the image p% to the right of the start of the image and move the whole image such that P' is placed, along with the whole image, horizontally p% to the right of the container.

**Question:**
- How to prove mathematically that these two different definitions of background-position property as equivalent?

E.g. taking the length of image `l`, length of container `L` then the difference between these `Δl=L-l`. First definition would offset the left border of image `x` pixels to the right such that
`x = p% of Δl = (Δl*p)/100 pixels`

For css-trick's definition: The left border of image would be offset by x pixels such that
`x = (p% of L) - (p% of l) = p% of (L-l) = p% of Δl = (Δl*p)/100 pixels`.

Well, Seems like I've proved it myself while writing the question.

Comment: Related maybe: [How does CSS computation for background percentages work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648245/how-does-css-computation-for-background-percentages-work) The description given by CSS-Tricks is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although it's CSS related it's more suited to math.exchange.

Comment: I don't know whether MSE would allow this type of question. It's a programming-mathematical question?

Comment: @BoltClock I did read your answer there. You explained it nicely.

Comment: Lemme pop over and ask the Math SE mods... (note this may take more than a few minutes, give us a day or so to handle migration flags and please do not cross-post in the meantime!)

Comment: Try drawing a circle with a percentage radius using SVG, it will either use a percentage of the x (width) or y (height), but obviously not both.